# Android:material design icons using unicode

Tags: android, textview, android-icons

I went through an android application where the developer has used TextView to display icon.Text set on textview was in string.xml like `<string name="icAbout">\ue900</string>`.The actual icon to be displayed was nowhere in the project. I just want to know what is that string and how it displays actual icon when set on textview.
The textview is like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIcIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dpSize50"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dpSize50"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dpSize15"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_border_app_color_solid_trans"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="IC"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
```

Comment: That's a drawable.xml as the background. Check for it.

Comment: developer has set that in activity file and used **setTypeface** method to draw a icon on textview

Comment: @RahulKhurana: yes he has used custom textview and and it has a setTypeface method.But from where the string representation comes?Is there any source material to read.

Comment: in setTypeface method the first parameter is used as TYPE_FACE in which  font file name is used

Comment: @RahulKhurana: yes it is there,But what if i want to add new icon for "Contact us" to it.How can i get the string representation of this.Is there any advantage of setting icons like this?

Comment: yes @Androidjack using icon from the font files will help to limit the increase in app size. for example if we are using more than 10 icons in the app this will increase the app size .. but if we use just one font file then it will be less in size

Comment: which font file is being used while using setTypeface method

Comment: @Androidjack could you provide the file name used while making typeface

Comment: @RahulKhurana: font file name is "hell.ttf" in assets folder.

Comment: just open that file name in any text editor and let me know the actual name. Its shown at the top of that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125600/discussion-between-android-jack-and-rahul-khurana).